# Proving Kernels and Cokernels exist in Category of Short exact Sequences

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Suppose $A$ is an abelian category. Then, we can define a category $Ses(A)$ of short exact sequences in $A$. I proved that the category is additive but I am not sure how to prove that this category has kernels and cokernels.

Comment: This question is answered in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220215/ You should do the obvious thing: for a morphism of s.e.s. $(f,g,h)$ take the kernels and cokernels of $f,g,h$. The resulting sequences $0 \to \ker f \to \ker g \to \ker h$ and $\operatorname{coker} f \to \operatorname{coker} g \to \operatorname{coker} h \to 0$ won't be exact on the right and on the left respectively; the inexactness is given by the snake lemma. But one can fix these sequences to make them exact and check that this way one obtains kernel and cokernel in $Ses (A)$ (see the link for details).

Comment: Note that kernels and cokernels won't behave well with respect to each other and the category $Ses (A)$ is not abelian.

Comment: Oh thank you for the link. The solution is not as nice as I hoped.

Comment: The solution is nice, in my opinion: you should try the obvious thing, which doesn't work for obvious reasons, but then it may be fixed in an obvious way :-) Of course, some work is needed to verify that the result satisfies the universal property of (co)kernels in $Ses (A)$.

Comment: I don't understand what Martin means by: It factors through the non-exact cokernel of $f^∗$. What is the non-exact cokernel he is referring to?

Comment: There implicitly another category is considered: the category of short not necessarily exact sequences, and he means to take the cokernel in this category, which is just taking the cokernel componentwise. But, you may try to start to read the 'addendum', it aims to answer this behaviour.