# Kernels and cokernels for the category of long exact sequences

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories, additive-categories

I've seen in many places, including Weibel's excellent book, that the category of short exact sequences (in an abelian category) has kernels and cokernels, although it is not abelian.

However, I cannot find any analogous information about the category of long exact sequences, so:

Are there kernels and cokernels in this category? In other words, is it pre-abelian?

Thank you!

Comment: Exact sequences in which category? Abelian groups or something more general?

Comment: I'm thinking about long exact sequences in an abelian category. However, because of Freyd's Theorem, I believe that it would suffice to consider long exact sequences in the category of modules over a ring. But starting with an answer in abelian groups would be great, since probably the answer would be the same.

Comment: Where exactly does Weibel state that the category of short exact sequences in an abelian category has kernels and cokernels?

Comment: I don't remember whether Weibel explicitly say that or not, but he proves the Snake Lemma, that implies the assertion as you can see in the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220215/colimits-in-that-category-of-short-exact-sequences-of-abelian-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1